# Add Google Analytics to JQuery Mobile app that runs in Cordova

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, cordova-2.0.0

I have a JQuery Mobile app. I want to distribute the app natively using Cordova (PhoneGap). I want to use Google Analytics within my app. My question is, how do I do this?

I am familiar with using Google Analytics within a Webpage. Because JQuery Mobile relies on standard HTML, JS, and CSS, I thought I could just copy and paste the Google Analytics JavaScript in my .html. However, I do not see any activity being logged.

What could I be doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Thank you!